# Android passing data to an Activity Class ?

Tags: android

When we start an Activity, is there anyway to get access to the object of the class, so that i can call the set data in the class. Something like

```
  Intent intent=new Intent (a.this, b.class);
  startActivity(intent);
```

Now i know there should be an object of b.class on the heap, and before the onCreate of the object is created, i want to pass some data to the class. Now i know i can do the same with Bundles, but passing objects through Bundles gets ugly. If i have the reference to the b.class i could call methods of the class ? Am i making sense. Is this possible ?

Kind Regards,

Comment: the b class is the activity you are starting. you have more than a reference to the class, in the onCreate you have an instance. And bundles/intent extras are the way to pass data between acitivities.

Answer (score 0):

This Would be your Manifest and this class can be used to set the value and then get the value in any of the Project java Class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="package name"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/somee" android:label="@string/app_name" android:noHistory="true" android:name="MainApplication" >
        <activity android:name=".first Page" android:noHistory="true"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and then in your main Application

```
public class MainApplication extends Application{

    private static MainApplication instance;
    private String _sUserId;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        instance=this;
    }

    public static Main Application getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    public void setUserId(String s){
        _sUserId=s;
    }

    public String getUserId(){
        return _sUserId;
```

}

and you can get values and set values in any java files like

```
   MainApplication o=((MainApplication)getApplicationContext());
        Integer UserID=o.getUserID();//you need to set user where you want to  to get the value of user id
```

Comment: you can also send float Value integer according to your need

Comment: Like i said i dont want to use Bundles. Is there no way of getting a reference of the class that the intent started.

Comment: Yea u  in your main application get its context i will edit the code

Answer (score 0):

"Is this possible?" - probably: yes. If both activities "live" in the same process you could acquire/hold a reference to B from A and call any public method and/or write to any public variable. However:

"Am I making sense?" - probably: no. For starters, keeping a reference to one activity from another would probably mean your memory footprint will be larger than needed (and probably larger than you expect as well: your activity B is probably used to inflate B's layout, which will not be cleaned up if B stays around). Also, what do you do if your activity is started by some other component than A? Will every such component need to have a reference to B in order to call the necessary public methods/vars beforehand? Not very nice.

In general an activity's interface should be described in terms of the Intents that can be used to start it. This includes: Actions for which it is started, Data that it should perform the Actions on, and Extras to set up the Activity. Since you already stated you know how to use Bundles (and the other, rather incomplete, answer gives you a simple example) I would only say: go for that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use global variable with keyword `static`. define your object in your class e.g SampleClass, then call the variable in onCreate method, SampleClass.yourObject.